# How will get part data of collections' MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

Can someone to explain about selecting part of collection? I have as a nested structure as example:

```
{
    some_list : [
        {
            'name': 'Alexander',
            'tasks': [
                'task_1',
                'task_2',
            ]
        },
        {
            'name': 'Stepan',
            'tasks': [
                'task_1',
                'task_2',
                'task_3',
            ]
        },
        {
            'name': 'Nikolay',
            'tasks': [
                'task_1'
            ]
        },
        {
            'name': 'Irina',
            'tasks': [
                'task_1',
                'task_2'
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get Alexander's tasks only (without unnecessary data)?

Comment: all of these tasks are in a single _document_?  If you will normally be dealing only with one user's tasks at a time is there a reason not to alter the schema to store each users' tasks in a separate document?  depending on how you will be using the data, you might even want to store each task as a separate document.   Consider your read and write patterns before finalizing the schema.

Comment: @asya-kamsky This example is not real :) It for learning.

Comment: so you question was about returning part of a document (not part of a collection).  Hopefully you noticed that it's only possible to return the first matching sub-document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
coll.find({'some_list.name':'Alexander'},{'some_list.$' : 1, _id : 0}).pretty()
{
    "some_list" : [
        {
            "name" : "Alexander",
            "tasks" : [
                "task_1",
                "task_2"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need `$elemMatch`

```
rsAlgo:PRIMARY> db.algo.find({"some_list.name":"Alexander"},{"some_list":{$elemMatch:{"name":"Alexander"}}});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51bedddfd894dfcb21087fc2"), "some_list" : [ { "name" : "Alexander", "tasks" : [ "task_1", "task_2" ] } ] }
```

or use .pretty() for explain result

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("51bedddfd894dfcb21087fc2"),
        "some_list" : [
                {
                        "name" : "Alexander",
                        "tasks" : [
                                "task_1",
                                "task_2"
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```